# Using an expect Script to send the output of a command and store in a file

Tags: buffer, expect, out, spawn

Hi I am trying to store the output of a command run through a spawn ssh remote window into my local host, I am new to expect and am not able to figure out where I am wrong.
My Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
        /usr/bin/expect <<EOD
        spawn ssh mininet@$line
        expect "assword:"
        send -- "mininet\r"
        set output [open "outputfile.txt" "a+"]
        expect  "mininet@mininet-vm:*"
        send -- "ls\r"
        set outcome $expect_out(buffer)
        send "\r"
        puts $output "$outcome"
        close $output
        expect  "mininet@mininet-vm:*"
        send -- "exit\r"
        interact
        expect eof
EOD
done <read_ip.txt
```

I am getting the error

```
expect: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"expect  "mininet@mininet-vm:*""
```

Please can any body help me on this code.

Comment: Did you misspell "assword:"?  Or is this correct?

Comment: Hi e0k It doesn't matters, It is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You have your expect program in a shell heredoc. The shell will expand variables in the heredoc **before** launching expect. You have to protect expect's variables from the shell.

One way is to use a 'quoted' heredoc, and pass the shell variable to expect through the environment:

```
#!/bin/bash
export host                            ## an environment variable
while read host
do
    /usr/bin/expect <<'EOD'            ## note the quotes here
        spawn ssh mininet@$env(host)   ## get the value from the environment
        expect "assword:"
        send -- "mininet\r"
        set output [open "outputfile.txt" "a+"]
        expect  "mininet@mininet-vm:*"
        send -- "ls\r"
        set outcome $expect_out(buffer)
        send "\r"
        puts $output "$outcome"
        close $output
        expect  "mininet@mininet-vm:*"
        send -- "exit\r"
        expect eof                 ## don't want both "interact" and "expect eof"
EOD
done <read_ip.txt
```

Putting single quotes around the heredoc terminator means the whole heredoc acts like a single quoted string, and expect's variables are left for expect to handle.

You might also investigate the expect `log_file` command: you can enable and disable logging at will, much as you are doing manually here.