# How to read the send command output in expect script

Tags: python, bash, expect, sys

I have an expect script that will login to the remote server and execute a python script. In python script I have set `sys.exit(1)` for a certain condition so that it would stop execution when that condition is met. Is there way to know if python script stopped execution or ran fine?
(or) is there a way to read the output that python script produces (that is I would like to read output of `send "python pythonscript.py arg1\r"`). Any approach is fine. Please suggest ideas

expectscript.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

eval spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no user@******
expect "Password:"
send "password\r"
expect "$username$"
set prompt ":|#|\\\$"
set timeout -1
send "cd /Users/username/Documents/folder/\r"
send "python pythonscript.py arg1\r"
expect $prompt
```

Comment: I think you can find what you're looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614039/how-to-get-the-exit-code-of-spawned-process-in-expect-shell-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you need to `expect -re` to capture the output before the prompt:

```
send "cd /Users/username/Documents/folder/\r"
expect $prompt
send "python pythonscript.py arg1\r"
expect -re "(.+)$prompt"
set pythonOutput $expect_out(1,string)
```

expect buffers output in the `expect_out` array, and the array key `1,string` (note, **no space there**) contains the contents of the *first capturing parentheses* of the regex pattern.

Also note, the output will include the python command, and lines are ended with `\r\n`: so you can do something like:

```
set outputLines [lrange [lmap line [split $pythonOutput \n] {regsub {\r$} $line ""] 1 end]
```

Comment: Isn't there a race condition?! I.e couldn't `expect -re "(.+)$prompt"` potentially be executed after some output has already been produced, hence being futile?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you think of an example where this would fail?

Comment: Python is slow to execute, but if it was a faster-to-respond interaction, couldn't that send command produce output before `expect -re` gets to run? (The reason I'm asking, is because I'm working with a 100% deterministic script that sometimes produces results and sometimes it doesn't, and I believe only such a race condition could be to blame.) I think, ideally, Expect should've had a send-and-listen command to cover such cases atomically.

Comment: `send` does not produce any output: the spawned process does. The output is buffered. The expect command watches the buffer until a match is found. It's OK that output is produced before the expect command executes.

Comment: Given your god-level status, I've to take your word for it. But there remains some doubt in me on potential race conditions. I'd be happy to paste the code here if you don't mind.

Comment: I finally figured it out. Put a `sleep 0.5` before `expect -re` and my script works w/o a hiccup now. Seems like `expect -re` was actually getting executed too early, rather than late.

Comment: Generally, if you need to sleep your patterns are not precise enough. Run with `expect -d` and check the verbose debugging to see when your patterns match when you don't want them to.

Comment: This msg: `does "\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression "(.+)\n"? Gate "*\n"? gate=yes re=yes` is what I get from a `expect -re "(.+)\n"` if not done with a brief sleep in advance. Sleep solves it however. I could make the regex fancier, but why bother.

Comment: That pattern is really so vague as to be almost useless: match any line of text.

Comment: I don't see your pattern being all that much more exclusive either. To give you context, it's to extract the result of an openssl decryption of a file. You enter the pass (via send in this script), and soon after, openssl prints the result on the next line. You `expect -re` too soon, and you get nothing. Wait half a sec instead, and voila!

Comment: Assuming the openssl command ends after it emits the decrypted text, then after sending the password `expect eof`, and then parse `$expect_out(buffer)` in the same fashion I show above.

Comment: That was the trick! Thank you, god! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Run as command**

```
spawn ssh -c "python pythonscript.py arg1"
expect $prompt
```

Try to use `spawn -c` for executable commands as this will fetch the result back, sending them terminates after execution.